# How to design shopping cart data with Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore as my back-end. I have designed my data for the shopping cart like this:

```
cart--
     cartid--
           product--
                  id: 'dsdasd',
                  title: 'New Dress',
                  price: 10,
                  images: 'https://someurl/image.jpg
           totalPrice: 50,
           amount: 5
```

But I am not sure to use it. I'd like to hear some suggestions for this situation. I built it in React.js. How can I design my shopping cart data with Firestore? What should I use Firebase or Firestore?

Comment: Do you mean **Realtime Database** or Firestore?

Comment: What is wrong with this schema?

Comment: @VasilGarov Firestore

Comment: @AlexMamo I am not sure with the totalPrice. should I remove it from the database and generate it on client(e.g. product.price * amount)?

Comment: Yes, that might help otherwise you'll need to update those fields everytime a new product is added.

Answer (score 1):

I'd personally use Firestore, but it also depends on your needs and your app's requirements. You can read more about differences between the Realtime DB and Firestore [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore).

Talking about your data model, I'm not sure about your actual implementation (it's not clear from the question), but you may need two different collections: `products` and `carts`.
Every `cart` document will have a field (array/object) with all the products IDs in that cart. This way you can achieve data consistency, fetching product data from the actual product document every time you need it (for example displaying the cart).

The `totalPrice`field in the cart is probably unnecessary and leads to data inconsistency, because you need to update it when products in the cart change. It might be better to display the total price in the front end with a simple sum.

Comment: yeah, but if I put only product IDs in the cart document then I'll need to fetch for each product. or is there a way to fetch batch?

Comment: Since your front end is built with React, you might have, for example, a CartProduct component to display every product in the cart page that fetches product data indipendently.

Comment: this means that if there are 20 ids in the cart I need to fetch 20 times?

Comment: That's right, but that's not really expensive in terms of performance/costs and it's the only way to avoid data inconsistency.

Comment: thank you man but I found that I can use Cloud Functions or transactions in Firebase. These great features of Firebase and Google Cloud can help me a lot

Comment: Glad to hear, those are really great features! What did you think about how to solve your problems with cloud functions and transactions? Can you describe your strategy editing the original question?